# Makefile compiles all files even if file is not changed when .o files are placed in other floder

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to Makefile(Actually to programming). I had following makefile:-

```
$ cat Makefile 
VER = Debug

main: main.o Time.o
    g++ Object\ Code/main.o Object\ Code/Time.o -o ../$(VER)/main

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -o Object\ Code/main.o

Time.o: Time.cpp Time_.h
    g++ -c Time.cpp -o Object\ Code/Time.o

clean:
    rm Object\ Code/*.o
    rm ../$(VER)/main
```

makefile is in src folder

```
$ ls && pwd
main.cpp  Makefile  Object Code  Time.cpp  Time_.h
/home/Rahul/Devlopment/WorkSpace/Test C++/src
```

Object code is a Directory in src.

```
$ ls ..
Debug  Release  src
```

But whenver I change just one single file and try to use make it compiles all files:-

```
$ make
g++ -c main.cpp -o Object\ Code/main.o
g++ -c Time.cpp -o Object\ Code/Time.o
g++ Object\ Code/main.o Object\ Code/Time.o -o ../Debug/main
$ touch Time
Time.cpp     Time_.h  
$ touch Time_.h 
$ make
g++ -c main.cpp -o Object\ Code/main.o
g++ -c Time.cpp -o Object\ Code/Time.o
g++ Object\ Code/main.o Object\ Code/Time.o -o ../Debug/main
$ make
g++ -c main.cpp -o Object\ Code/main.o
g++ -c Time.cpp -o Object\ Code/Time.o
g++ Object\ Code/main.o Object\ Code/Time.o -o ../Debug/main
```

As a complete noob I have no Idea. Please help me.

Comment: `main` is dependent on `main.o` not `Object Code/main.o` etc

Comment: What @Neil Butterworth said: avoid spaces in filenames like the plague.

Answer (score 3):

The file `main.o` is not the same file as `Object\ Code/main.o`, and similarly for other files, and I would strongly advise you to avoid spaces in filenames and directories when developing programs. Setting up make to use separate directories is not entirely straightforward, and you should get your makefile working off a single directory before implementing multiple directories.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a target make requires your recipe to create the same file as the target: else you're lying to make.  A rule like this:

```
main.o: main.cpp
        <recipe>
```

is interpreted by make to say, "if you want to build a file `main.o` and you have a file `main.cpp` and `main.o` is out of date, then you can run this recipe `<recipe>` to do that".  But, your recipe doesn't build `main.o`, it builds `Object code/main.o`.  So the next time make goes through, it wants to build `main.o` and it doesn't exist, so make tries to build it again... etc.

Item #1: it's not possible to use paths containing spaces in makefiles.

Item #2: you should always use automatic variables like `$@` etc. to be sure your rules build the same thing that make expects.

Item #3: it's not useful to compile the source code into object files  in a hardcoded directory, then write the executable file to a variable directory (like `$(Ver)`)

Your makefile should look something like this:

```
CXX = g++
SOURCES = main.cpp Time.cpp
VER = Debug

$(VER)/main: $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(VER)/%.o)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(VER)/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
        rm -rf $(VER)
```

See [The GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) for details on all these things.